# Exporting source of built plugins in PDE Build

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, pde

I have a project that is made up of several features and plugins, and I want to export the source of the projects that have been built using PDE Build.

One of the reasons for this is that we have a large common plugin Subversion repository, for plugins common to all projects, that is checked out before the build (the entire common trunk. The problem is that some of the common plugins may not actually be included in the build, so if I would just take all the plugins that have been checked out from the repository I might get plugins that weren't in the actual build.

Is there a way to tell PDE Build to export the source when a plugin is built?

Answer (score 0):

for each plugin you can edit the build.properties file... it should be contained within your project folder: (you can also simply double-click on the plugin.xml file):

[image]

then you have to make checkboxes on the source code and include all within your build...

[image]

Remember: the build.properties files will be used by the pde-build!

you might also want to add these lines to your build.properties file (the build file for the build, not for the plugins)

```
############## SOURCE BUNDLE CONTROL ################
# Set this property to have source bundles created and output into build repository.
# This does NOT put them in the build output (e.g., product) itself.
# Valid values are: not set, built, all.
#       built = only source for bundles that are actually built/compiled in this run are output
#       all = all available source is collected and output
sourceBundleMode=all
individualSourceBundles=true
```

Comment: I tried this with one of the plugins; during the build a "plugin_name_source_1.0.0.x.yz" folder was created, but it doesn't contain any source files but only the manifest and project files. Do I have to set a flag in the "global" build.properties file used by the PDE headless build?

Comment: maybe you can simply change your build.poperties file for your build (i've added an example above)